# Why does this particular lens produce sunstars with long spokes?

Tags: sunlight, starbursts

This image was shot with a [Sony E 20mm f/2.8](https://www.sony.com/electronics/camera-lenses/sel20f28) on a Sony a7.  The lens is intended for an APS-C sensor, but I removed a baffle to shoot on the full-frame body.

[image: Sunstar shining through the branches of a tall tree]

I understand the basic physics of sunstars.  My question is why the sunstars from this particular lens have the giant spokes.  This is not due to anything about the composition of this particular shot; the lens always produces sunstars like this.

Edit 1: Yes, the sensor was filthy.  Other lenses used around the same time had normal sunstars.  I've since cleaned the sensor, and this effect still appears with this lens.

Edit 2: As requested, images of the font of the lens with the aperture at f/16, the smallest available.  The first image has a UV filter in place; the second does not.

[image: Photo of the lens, with a UV filter]
[image: Photo of the lens, without a UV filter]

Comment: Is the front element scratched? Or are there directional scratches in the coating of the front element (assuming it has a coating)?

Comment: I don't have a magnifying glass or other tool I could use to check for sure.  But I don't see any scratches with a basic visual inspection, and haven't noticed any other weird behavior with the lens that might be due to scratches. I purchased this on eBay, but it was listed as New condition and IIRC it seemed like it came in the original packaging.

Comment: Do you get the same exact shape when there isn't a pine tree between the camera and the sun?

Comment: "This is not due to anything about the composition of this particular shot; the lens always produces sunstars like this."

Comment: Can you provide an image of the aperture when it's stopped down? Can you provide more information about the full-frame modification?  What happens if you reverse the mod?  [Ken Rockwell](https://www.kenrockwell.com/sony/lenses/20mm-f28.htm) gets sunstars typical of rounded aperture blades.

Comment: Do you mean a photograph of the lens, or just an image taken with the lens when the aperture is stopped down?  The image in the post was taken at f/16, which is as small as this lens goes.  I used the steps here to remove the rear baffle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o46pqs4i3k

Comment: I'd like to see what the aperture itself looks like at the setting you use to create sunstars because that is a major factor in the appearance of sunstars.

Comment: @DanHicks When you shot the sunstar, did you have the filter on?  Can you shoot some more sunstars? (1) Without the UV filter.  (2) With the mod reversed, the rear baffle put back on the lens, both with and without the UV filter.

Answer (score 2):

Your lens design is not the only thing that affects diffraction, which is what produces sun stars or sun spikes.

*Everything* between the Sun and your camera that the light from the sun interacts with can diffract light and affect the results.

The shapes and sizes of the pine needles and branches of the tree between your lens and the sun will also play a role.